# What is the difference between npm init vite@latest and npm init vite?

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite

I recently started using vite to make my react apps as I grew tired of the excruciatingly long install times for create-react-app. However, as I looked online, I found different ways of making a vite app. On the official documentation, it says to use npm init vite@latest while other tutorials use npm init vite. Both require you to install different dependencies on your machine before you can run the commands. However, it appears that they both do essentially the same thing. Can anyone explain the difference between the 2 commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between the two, is, `npm init vite@latest` will download the latest version - and `npm init vite` will use `create-vite` **if you had it previously globally installed**, or it will fetch the latest version. that's it. Read below

When you get `@latest` on some tutorials, you can see it as an explicit information in order to not confuse the reader, but they should stipulate the following note.

Note:

> IF you had already the `create-vite` package **globally**
> installed, and for example, a **older version**, it will be what `npm init` uses.

So:

`npm init foo` fetches and runs the already installed create-foo OR the  latest create-foo from the registry if not.

`npm init foo@latest` fetches and runs the latest create-foo from the registry.

`npm init foo@1.2.3` runs create-foo@1.2.3 to install the package version **1.2.3**  specifically.